# using pip command says "command not found"

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, pip

I am using an m1 mac.
For some reason, pip isn't working in terminal or VScode. It just says "command not found". I recently deleted some python files from my computer since there were so many files and I didn't know their function. Could this have affected it? How can I fix this?

Comment: try `py -m pip`

Comment: 1. Check if pip is installed with command `pip --version` or `pip3 --version`.
2. If its installed, try reinstalling Python and then pip again.

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen `py` on Mac?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to reinstall python3 if you haven't already. Also, if pip is there and isn't working you could try running it from the file location (this is what I do). You may also need to add it to path so that it is a globally accessible command. I thought this was done by default and may be fixed with a python reinstall, but if not here is an article on how to do it on mac.

https://wpbeaches.com/how-to-add-to-the-shell-path-in-macos-using-terminal/